Is it better for social media content to generate direct traffic or search volume?
Lets say that I posted some viral social media content that got many people wanting to try out the product.
Would it be better to link my website in the description, include the URL of the website in the content, etc (generating direct traffic)
OR
Only mention the name/brand of my product, and let users search my brand in Google, generating search volume for my brand?

The less steps an user has to take to get to your product the more user will consume your product. In other words: Sending users to a search engine is just an obstacle. There's also quite a big chance that both the social media post and your product are already monitored by Google, for instance by using analytics. This will have an impact on your ranking. However, by how much exactly, and what sending users through the search engine will do is unknown. You could simply do both .... and let the user choose.
